# Integer cannot be cast to Long

Tags: java, android

I am keeping track of row ids in the shared preferences for my sqlite database. I was using an int, but then I realized that maybe long would be more adequate for this since the id value could become huge over time. I am getting this error when I try to getLong from shared preference: *java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long*

```
sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    workoutId = sharedPreferences.getLong("workoutId", 0);
```

My workoutId initialize code is a global variable `private long workoutId;`
I'm not sure where it is getting integer value from in the error message.
Or maybe int will suite just fine?

Comment: @NIKHILAGGARWAL `0F` is a `float`-literal. I do not see how this could help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with your default value which is Integer.

You should use

```
workoutId = sharedPreferences.getLong("workoutId", 0L);
```

OR

```
workoutId = sharedPreferences.getLong("workoutId", (long) 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I just tried both methods and still got the same error.  This is very weird.

Comment: I figured out my problem. It was still reading the settings from when I had it as an int. I cleared my emulator's data and it worked. Thanks!